# Update data in RecyclerView when scrolling through tabs in ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have 3 fragments, say A, B, C, a being the centre fragment and also the fragment which shows when the app launches. A have a database where data can be changed from fragment A. Upon scrolling to either B or C, I want the data to be updated and shown in a RecyclerView. Currently I have the update code in the onCreateView() of the fragment, but since android doesn't call onCreateView() for every time the page is changed, the data does not get updated.

I tried writing a function to refresh the lists and put to `addOnPageScrolledListener()` in the main activity, but that gives a null pointer exception.

How do I get the data to change whenever I scroll to a fragment?

Fragment Code:

```
public class RecentFragment extends Fragment {

private DBHelper dbHelper;
private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    dbHelper = new DBHelper(getActivity());
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list, container, false);
    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.event_list_view);
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    linearLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
    ArrayList<String> arrayList = dbHelper.getData();
    FavouritesListAdapter listAdapter = new FavouritesListAdapter(getActivity(),arrayList);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
    return rootView;
}
public void updateList(){
    ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    FavouritesListAdapter listAdapter = new FavouritesListAdapter(getActivity(),arrayList);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this method  public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) returns true if this fragment's UI is currently visible to the user, false if it is not. In your case which fragment is currently shown in the viewpager.

Comment: I don't want to know which fragment is being shown. I want to update the data in the RecyclerView in the fragment.